# How to create a new Oracle database programmatically with Java?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I want to create a blank Oracle 12c database programmaticaltlly with Java. But if I use getConnection() method in JDBC driver, it does not allow me to run a CREATE DATABASE statement with since I have to mention a spwcific SID/service name for the connection.

Is there a way that I can connect to Oracle server without specifying a service name/SID in the connection string? and create a blank database from within a Java application?

Comment: I don't think it is possible.  Even if it was, I'm not sure it is advisable ... because you would need to give the java client the database's admin password to do this.  (I would be very hesitant to lend those "crown jewels" to an application that might be insecure ...)

Comment: Are you certain that you are using "database" here in the Oracle sense of the word?  What lots of other RDBMS products call a "database" is more like what Oracle calls a "schema".  In Oracle, you'd generally only have one database on a server.  Or, depending on the version or edition, perhaps you want to create a new PDB in an existing CDB?

Comment: @StephenC Yes, I understand that. This application is for internal use only. Currently it has the capability of performing unattended copying of database between different Oracle servers. My need is to be able to add a new database service and then do the copying (export>import) to that new database.

Comment: @JustinCave yes. I'm reffering to a database. Not schema. My need is to create a new database instance/service programmaticaltlly with a given SID.

Comment: My advice would be to look for another way of scripting Oracle admin.  You could start reading here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18727_01/doc.121/e13592/T369584T425474.htm.   And https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-shell-scripting.  If you really want to you could use `Process` / `ProcessBuilder` to run a (shell) command from Java.

Comment: @StephenC this looks good!. Thanks!

Comment: Pluggable databases can easily be controlled through Java - you connect to the container and run a `create pluggable database ...`  statement. Do you really need a complete new instance? Why wouldn't a PDB be enough?

Comment: IHMO you should 1st explain why do you need it. What is the purpose. In case of maintenance of testing environments you can use PDB (plug-gable databases) or Docker images. The "real" database creation can be done via OCI driver (from SQLPLUS). And also do not confuse a database creation with database schema creation. Another  - even faster way - is to use rman co create a database from backup set.

Comment: Creation of database in not so easy. At least on Linux you might need also root's privs. to change kernel parameters. It is not easy to bypass DBAs.